# Is there a way to add WHM ssh keys that are authorized to account ssh keys and authorize them automatically?

Tags: ssh, cpanel, ssh-keys, whm

Since we've turned off passwords for security purposes, I was hoping there was a script or some other way to automatically add WHM authorized keys to account level ssh public keys and have them automatically authorized.

Answer (score 0):

You muste be to create a script post create acct (/scripts/postwwwacct example) or standarized script. See more on https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/Guide+to+Standardized+Hooks+-+Script+Hooks